# Is it possible to enable remote debugger port programmatically for Embedded Safari Webkit screens in Cocoa Application

Tags: selenium, cocoa, safari-web-inspector

I have a hybrid Application(MacOS) that Embeds Webkit (Safari). In order to automate (UI Automation) this screen, I am wondering if its possible to use selenium. To do that, what options do I have?

So far, I am able to inspect the elements on the Embedded Webview by running command: `defaults write NSGlobalDomain WebKitDeveloperExtras -bool true` using WebInspector.

I hope, that if I could enable remote debugging port within this application, I would be able to interact with the Embedded Webkit view using selenium.

1. Is this assumption right?
2. Is it really possible at all to interact with embedded safari webkit in a cocoa application programmatically?
3. How can I enable remote debugging port while initializing the Webview in my Cocoa application.

Thanks in Advance.